# MassTransit - UseInMemoryOutbox after upgrade to version 8.1

Tags: masstransit

After upgrade MassTransit to version 8.1, the following registration code:

```
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox(); // Obsolete
    })

    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
    });
});
```

is reported as obsolete with, the following error message:

> InMemoryOutboxConfigurationExtensions.UseInMemoryOutbox(IConsumerConfigurator, Action)' is obsolete: 'Use the IRegistrationContext overload instead.

I understand that I should use `IRegistrationContext` but I don't know where can I get it from?

For some reasons I wouldn't like to move InMemoryOutbox enabling to endpoint level or to consumer definition class.

Are there any other options?

Comment: I'll have to think about this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional overloads [have been added](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/pull/4642), so that the registration context can be passed. They'll be in the latest prerelease package and released with 8.1.1.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox(context);
    })

    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and patch.